# Variable within xpath is not working correctly

Tags: python, xpath

This works:

```
i = 1
num = '3.1.' + str(i)
if (num == '3.1.1'):
    print("correct")
```

And this works:

```
num = '3.1.1'
for content in tree.findall(".//Section/Section/Section[@SectionNumber='{}']".format(num)):
    print("correct")
```

But this doesn't work:
(No error, just didn't print correct)

```
i = 1
num = '3.1.' + str(i)
for content in tree.findall(".//Section/Section/Section[@SectionNumber='{}']".format(num)):
    print("correct")
```

---

What is wrong when I combining the string? Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is it simply failing to match?

Comment: @larsks No error, just didn't print "correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the behavior you've described. The following Python code exercises all three examples presented in your question:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

data = """
<Document>
  <Section>
      <Section>
          <Section SectionNumber="3.1.1">
              This is a test.
          </Section>
      </Section>
  </Section>
</Document>
"""


tree = etree.fromstring(data)

print("Test 1")
i = 1
num = "3.1." + str(i)
if num == "3.1.1":
    print("correct")
print()

print("Test 2")
num = "3.1.1"
for content in tree.findall(
    ".//Section/Section/Section[@SectionNumber='{}']".format(num)
):
    print("correct")
print()

print("Test 3")
i = 1
num = "3.1." + str(i)
for content in tree.findall(
    ".//Section/Section/Section[@SectionNumber='{}']".format(num)
):
    print("correct")
print()
```

Running the above code produces:

```
Test 1
correct

Test 2
correct

Test 3
correct
```

If you run this code and get different results, or if you can update your question to include a complete, runnable example that produces the behavior you've described, I would be happy to take a closer look.